# customize wordpress page editor for single page websites

Tags: php, wordpress

So i build a one page website theme in wordpress but now i want to have the layout from my site in the page editor is there a way to program this or is it even possible in wordpress? For example have three text inputs next to each other and get the value of each input and put it in the three paragraphs in my theme. I'm new to wordpress so sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at this.  You need to do some PHP in the body of your page, but it lets you do what(I think) you're trying to do.  https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: EDIT may: Advancedcustomfileds is awsome! Finaly got the money together and i have to say it is worth the investment